# FB restrictions to read from stream of non-friend posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-fql, privacy

Does any restriction exists in FQL if I need to read a post from **stream** table, where PostID is some arbitrary id of non-friend's public post?

In other words, does reading from stream table currently only means I am allowed to read posts that I am friend/follower of?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not the case, but you'll need a User Access Token with `read_stream` permissions according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/#permissions even if you want o access public posts.

Be aware that with v2.0 of the Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-read the `read_stream` permission *is reserved for apps that replicate the Facebook client on platforms that don’t have a native client*.